# Xamarin: How to set a box view that has 16:9 aspect to fill horizontally and require necessary height?

Tags: user-interface, xamarin.forms

I just want to make sure no matter if the user rotate the phone, my box view will always be filled the horizontal, while keeping the same aspect.

Basically I am using FFImageLoading for displaying the image, however, if there is no image, I still want to keep that space and put some placeholder for it.

Comment: Did you ever solve the problem?